# Ajax call is not firing in modal popup : No error is showing in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a button inside a modal popup and I want to make an AJAX request after that button is clicked, however the AJAX request is not fired.

When I change the button to `type="submit"` the click event works but the page reloads and the AJAX call is cancelled. I tried to stop the page reload with `e.prevenDefault()` but it stops every step. There are no errors in the console or network tab.

```js
function Click_btnFirst() {
  document.getElementById("txtRule_No").value = "1";
}

function Click_btnPrev() {
  if (document.getElementById("txtRule_No").value > 1) {
    document.getElementById("txtRule_No").value = document.getElementById("txtRule_No").value - 1;
  }
}

function Click_btnNext() {
  if (document.getElementById("txtRule_No").value < document.getElementById("MaxRule_No").value) {
    document.getElementById("txtRule_No").value = parseInt(document.getElementById("txtRule_No").value) + parseInt(1);
  }
}

function Click_btnLast() {
  document.getElementById("txtRule_No").value = document.getElementById("MaxRule_No").value;
}

function Click_btnSubmit(e) {
        //e.preventDefault();
        alert('!!@@##');
        var valdata = $("#PortfolioRuleOrderForm").serialize();
        alert(valdata);
        //console.log();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/WEB/ups/Order.aspx/order_change',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
            data: valdata,
            async: false,
            //data: { "txtRule_No": txtRule_No, "MaxRule_No": MaxRule_No, "PortfolioID": PortfolioID, "RuleID": RuleID },
            success: function () {
                alert("Done!");
                alert(data);
                console.log('success', data);
            },
            failure: function () {
                alert("Failure!");
            }
        });
        //console.log();
        //e.preventDefault();
       
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-body" style="margin-left:-140px;">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <form id="PortfolioRuleOrderForm">
        <table class="inputForm" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; table-layout: fixed">
          <thead>
            <tr height="18">
              <td>Portfolio Rule Order</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tfoot>
            <tr>
              <td style="vertical-align: middle">

                <table>
                  <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                      <td>Rule no:</td>
                      <td>
                        <input type="Text" id="txtRule_No" name="txtRule_No" value="<%= long.Parse(Request.QueryString[" RuleNo "]) %>"/>
                        <input type="hidden" id="MaxRule_No" name="MaxRule_No" value="<%= long.Parse(Request.QueryString[" MaxRuleNo "]) %>"/>
                        <input type="hidden" id="PortfolioID" name="PortfolioID" value="<%= long.Parse(Request.QueryString[" PortfolioID "]) %>"/>
                        <input type="hidden" id="RuleID" name="RuleID" value="<%= long.Parse(Request.QueryString[" RuleID "]) %>"/>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <input type="button" id="Firstbtn" runat="server" value="|<" OnClick="Click_btnFirst()" />
                        <input type="button" id="Prevbtn" runat="server" value="<" OnClick="Click_btnPrev()" />
                        <input type="button" id="Nextbtn" runat="server" value=">" OnClick="Click_btnNext()" />
                        <input type="button" id="Lastbtn" runat="server" value=">|" OnClick="Click_btnLast()" />
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tfoot>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="footerrow" height="24">
              <td align="right">
                <input class="button" id="btnSubmit" type="button" value="OK" name="OK" OnClick="Click_btnSubmit()" />
                <input class="button" id="btnCancel" onclick=" top.window.close();" type="button" value="Cancel" name="btnCancel" data-dismiss="modal" /></td>
            </tr>
          </tfoot>
        </table>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're calling a function OnClick="btnSubmit_Click()" but that function doesn't exist.  You've already attached an onClick event listener to the button click.

Comment: @NathanChampion sorry I will edit my code

Comment: Where are you defining the values for txtRule_No, MaxRule_No, PortfolioID and RuleID?  Should it be passing document.getElementById(Id).value ?

Comment: @NathanChampion all these values I got from Request.QueryString then I am parsing these values and assigned it to input types . text and hidden textbox in the form

Comment: Hi , not even `alert('!!@@##');` pop up ?

Comment: You are running code in HTML controls without `runat="server"`. You should be getting errors for that. Use server controls. Also, the code to get the query strings has nested double-quotes in them.

Comment: @Swati yes I am getting the alert('!!@@##'); and alert(valdata); but after that nothing . No error in console or network tab . nothing

Comment: @wazz in form tag should I add runat="server" ? Are you talking about this Request.QueryString[" RuleNo "] [nested double qoutes]

Comment: Are you sure this is `contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'` right ? Because `.serialize()` with create query string with parameter separated by `&` so there is no need add content type json because here you  are sending simple string .

Comment: @Swati I will remove contentType amd test it . Thanks for the reply